# 403 when trying to update Google Sites with python script

Tags: python, gdata, google-sites

I tried to updating my google site but i keep getting this

> **server responded with: 403, Not authorized to write to this feed**

This occurs when i am updating content, creating new site, creating a new page in the site.

However, I am able to retrieve the contents of the site and see the webpages it contains. I am the creator of the site. In addition, i am using clientLogin() to provide authentication to the google site. The server i plan to run this script on does not have a gui thus I cant use gauth or oath (unless somone has a way of doing it).

Comment: You don't need a gui for oauth? Example code (altho PHP, logic can be directly convered into Python): https://github.com/Torxed/Scripts/tree/master/PHP

Comment: thank you will look at it and try it out. Oauth requires registration to app engine if i am not wrong. i am not registered to google apps as its a paid service.

Answer (score 0):

According to Google themselves, the [ClientLogin](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/AuthForInstalledApps) method should be replaced with OAuth.

> Important: ClientLogin has been officially deprecated as of April 20, 2012. It will continue to work as per our deprecation policy, but we encourage you to migrate to OAuth 2.0 as soon as possible.

And i'd suggest using a OAuth lib rather than doing it on your own at first.
[python-oauth2](https://github.com/simplegeo/python-oauth2) is a nice one.

---

**Edit:** Google has [OAuth API](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/oauth/) built in to the app-engine module if you have that.

```
from google.appengine.api import oauth
```

Otherwise for manual OAuth implementation: [oauth google using python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1215033/oauth-google-using-python) (I won't post example code here cause that guy deserves the ups he can get.

Comment: i am not registered under google apps as its a paid service. Doesnt oauth require some registration?

Comment: Ah right, sorry.. I just assumed you had one cause i did when using Google Sites (their services go hand in hand)..

Comment: Yeah. but they changed their model to make it a paid service. Is there any other ways ard this?
Acutally I didnt plan to use google sites. I am trying to upload a chart from google spreadsheets to a website and it shld auto update when i change the data on the spreadsheet. But using their "publish to website" and their documentation doesnt seem to work. 
However, publishing as a image does work but the graph isnt interactive. 
hope you can help

Comment: Yes, check my latest edit OR my example code (based on PHP) https://github.com/Torxed/Scripts/tree/master/PHP **OR** use the `oauth2` library.

Comment: with the oauth2 i don need to register at all? how will it do the key exchange?

Comment: Long story short, you send the different keys at the key exchanges or via the PHP module (convert it into Python) it's done automaticly by following urls, havn't used the OAuth 2 modules much since i have written my own code for Python.. just don't have it here but i based it on my own PHP code so.. You generate a token, request an access key, you sign your requests and all is well. This is the short version..

Comment: Thank you. 
I tried using the example py script given by google . Login error.
I am not sure if i am providing the correct credentials

Comment: Probably not. We need some example code (blur out your keys) to understand where you're going wrong. I'd even suggest starting a new SO question where you ask "Google Sites - OAuth login error" or something as such.